# A matrix with negative determinants

Tags: determinant

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ real matrix and $det(A)<0$ .

Does there exixt a positive number $\delta$ such that $\|Ax\|\geq\delta\|x\|$, for  all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: every linear operator is bounded and continuous in finite dimensional space -  linear operator  can be represent as a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question becomes easier if you square both sides (using nonnegativity) and divide by $x^Tx$ (which is again nonnegative, assuming $x \neq 0$):
$$\frac{x^T A^TA x}{x^Tx} \geq \delta^2. $$
By the Rayleigh quotient:
$$\frac{x^T A^TA x}{x^Tx} \geq \lambda_{\text{min}}(A^TA). $$
The matrix $A^T A$ ispositive definite as $x^T(A^TA)x = ||Ax||^2 > 0$ if $x \neq 0$. The smallest eigenvalue is therefore strictly positive. So, $\delta = \sqrt{\lambda_{\text{min}}(A^TA)}$ does the trick.